# How to get values from object of dirty form and put into Array instead?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working with a project where I need to only submit dirty values to an API including the form value ID and the value from within the form (that has been changed). In order to get the changed form values, I am using the following function:

```
getDirtyValues(form: any) {
  let dirtyValues = {};

  Object.keys(form.controls).forEach((key) => {
    let currentControl = form.controls[key];

    if (currentControl.dirty) {
      if (currentControl.controls) {
        dirtyValues[key] = this.getDirtyValues(currentControl);
      } else {
        dirtyValues[key] = currentControl.value;
      }
    }
  });

  return dirtyValues;
}
```

This function is returning me an object containing the value and changed form item. For example, if I have a form where:

index 0 = "First slot", index 1 = "Second slot", index 2 = "Third slot"

and I change the form of index 2 to "Changed slot", I will receive the following:

```
{
  "2": {
    "label": "Changed slot"
  }
}
```

How can I extract the id (2, in this case), and the new label ("Changed slot", in this case) in order to post to an API. For example, `postToApi(index, changedValue)`? I would like to be able to run through a loop of items using a `forEach()` so if I have multiple changed values returned from the `getDirtyValues(...)` function, then I can post each changed value to the API. But since the data is not in an array, I of course cannot do this.

Comment: Object.keys(obj) ... Maybe this could help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

To create an array, transform the input object to an array of key-value pairs using `Object.entries()`.  Map it, flatten the result, and reject nulls.

```js
let fc = {
  foo: {
    dirty: true,
    value: 'bar'
  },
  notDirty: {
    dirty: false,
    value: 'cleanbar'
  },
  recursive: {
    dirty: true,
    controls: {
      nested: {
        dirty: true,
        value: 'nestedBar'
      },
      deeperRecursion: {
        dirty: true,
        controls: {
          deepest: {
            dirty: true,
            value: 'deepestBar'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function getDirtyValues(form) {
  return Object.entries(form.controls).map(([key, currentControl]) => {
    if (currentControl.dirty) {
      return (currentControl.controls) ? getDirtyValues(currentControl) : { [key]: currentControl.value };
    }
  }).flat(Infinity).filter(el => el);
}


console.log(getDirtyValues({ controls: fc }))
```